# solve error : log already in use with atomikos with multiple instances

Tags: java, atomikos

I am facing an issue only on live server with atomikos, on my local server it works perfectly.

the issue i am facng on the server is

Error in init(): Log already in use?

complete exception stack trace

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Log already in use?
    at com.atomikos.icatch.standalone.UserTransactionServiceImp.createDefault(UserTransactionServiceImp.java:205)
    at com.atomikos.icatch.standalone.UserTransactionServiceImp.init(UserTransactionServiceImp.java:265)
    at com.atomikos.icatch.config.UserTransactionServiceImp.init(UserTransactionServiceImp.java:405)
    at com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionImp.checkSetup(UserTransactionImp.java:100)
    at com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionImp.begin(UserTransactionImp.java:115)
    at com.vs.framework.service.BlfServiceAtomIkosBean.executeService(BlfServiceAtomIkosBean.java:32)
    at com.dbhl.app.presentation.action.CreateUnitTypeAction.execute(CreateUnitTypeAction.java:128)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.servlet.ExecuteAction.execute(ExecuteAction.java:58)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.AbstractExecuteAction.execute(AbstractExecuteAction.java:67)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.ActionCommandBase.execute(ActionCommandBase.java:51)
    at org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:190)
    at org.apache.commons.chain.generic.LookupCommand.execute(LookupCommand.java:304)
    at org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:190)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.ComposableRequestProcessor.process(ComposableRequestProcessor.java:283)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:462)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler.invoke(JkCoyoteHandler.java:190)
    at org.apache.jk.common.HandlerRequest.invoke(HandlerRequest.java:291)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.invoke(ChannelSocket.java:769)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.processConnection(ChannelSocket.java:698)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket$SocketConnection.runIt(ChannelSocket.java:891)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:690)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
com.atomikos.icatch.SysException: Error in init(): Log already in use?
    at com.atomikos.icatch.standalone.UserTransactionServiceImp.init(UserTransactionServiceImp.java:333)
    at com.atomikos.icatch.config.UserTransactionServiceImp.init(UserTransactionServiceImp.java:405)
    at com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionImp.checkSetup(UserTransactionImp.java:100)
    at com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionImp.begin(UserTransactionImp.java:115)
    at com.vs.framework.service.BlfServiceAtomIkosBean.executeService(BlfServiceAtomIkosBean.java:32)
    at com.dbhl.app.presentation.action.CreateUnitTypeAction.execute(CreateUnitTypeAction.java:128)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.servlet.ExecuteAction.execute(ExecuteAction.java:58)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.AbstractExecuteAction.execute(AbstractExecuteAction.java:67)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.ActionCommandBase.execute(ActionCommandBase.java:51)
    at org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:190)
    at org.apache.commons.chain.generic.LookupCommand.execute(LookupCommand.java:304)
    at org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:190)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.ComposableRequestProcessor.process(ComposableRequestProcessor.java:283)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:462)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler.invoke(JkCoyoteHandler.java:190)
    at org.apache.jk.common.HandlerRequest.invoke(HandlerRequest.java:291)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.invoke(ChannelSocket.java:769)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.processConnection(ChannelSocket.java:698)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket$SocketConnection.runIt(ChannelSocket.java:891)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:690)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Log already in use?
    at com.atomikos.icatch.standalone.UserTransactionServiceImp.createDefault(UserTransactionServiceImp.java:205)
    at com.atomikos.icatch.standalone.UserTransactionServiceImp.init(UserTransactionServiceImp.java:265)
    ... 31 more
Nested exception is: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Log already in use?
    at com.atomikos.icatch.standalone.UserTransactionServiceImp.createDefault(UserTransactionServiceImp.java:205)
    at com.atomikos.icatch.standalone.UserTransactionServiceImp.init(UserTransactionServiceImp.java:265)
    at com.atomikos.icatch.config.UserTransactionServiceImp.init(UserTransactionServiceImp.java:405)
    at com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionImp.checkSetup(UserTransactionImp.java:100)
    at com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionImp.begin(UserTransactionImp.java:115)
    at com.vs.framework.service.BlfServiceAtomIkosBean.executeService(BlfServiceAtomIkosBean.java:32)
    at com.dbhl.app.presentation.action.CreateUnitTypeAction.execute(CreateUnitTypeAction.java:128)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.servlet.ExecuteAction.execute(ExecuteAction.java:58)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.AbstractExecuteAction.execute(AbstractExecuteAction.java:67)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.ActionCommandBase.execute(ActionCommandBase.java:51)
    at org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:190)
    at org.apache.commons.chain.generic.LookupCommand.execute(LookupCommand.java:304)
    at org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:190)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.ComposableRequestProcessor.process(ComposableRequestProcessor.java:283)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:462)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler.invoke(JkCoyoteHandler.java:190)
    at org.apache.jk.common.HandlerRequest.invoke(HandlerRequest.java:291)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.invoke(ChannelSocket.java:769)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.processConnection(ChannelSocket.java:698)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket$SocketConnection.runIt(ChannelSocket.java:891)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:690)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
ERROR: the specified log seems to be in use already. Make sure that no other instance is running, or kill any pending process if needed.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Log already in use?
    at com.atomikos.icatch.standalone.UserTransactionServiceImp.createDefault(UserTransactionServiceImp.java:205)
    at com.atomikos.icatch.standalone.UserTransactionServiceImp.init(UserTransactionServiceImp.java:265)
    at com.atomikos.icatch.config.UserTransactionServiceImp.init(UserTransactionServiceImp.java:405)
    at com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionImp.checkSetup(UserTransactionImp.java:100)
    at com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionImp.rollback(UserTransactionImp.java:140)
    at com.vs.framework.service.BlfServiceAtomIkosBean.executeService(BlfServiceAtomIkosBean.java:80)
    at com.dbhl.app.presentation.action.CreateUnitTypeAction.execute(CreateUnitTypeAction.java:128)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.servlet.ExecuteAction.execute(ExecuteAction.java:58)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.AbstractExecuteAction.execute(AbstractExecuteAction.java:67)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.ActionCommandBase.execute(ActionCommandBase.java:51)
    at org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:190)
    at org.apache.commons.chain.generic.LookupCommand.execute(LookupCommand.java:304)
    at org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:190)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.ComposableRequestProcessor.process(ComposableRequestProcessor.java:283)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:462)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler.invoke(JkCoyoteHandler.java:190)
    at org.apache.jk.common.HandlerRequest.invoke(HandlerRequest.java:291)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.invoke(ChannelSocket.java:769)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.processConnection(ChannelSocket.java:698)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket$SocketConnection.runIt(ChannelSocket.java:891)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:690)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
com.atomikos.icatch.SysException: Error in init(): Log already in use?
    at com.atomikos.icatch.standalone.UserTransactionServiceImp.init(UserTransactionServiceImp.java:333)
    at com.atomikos.icatch.config.UserTransactionServiceImp.init(UserTransactionServiceImp.java:405)
    at com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionImp.checkSetup(UserTransactionImp.java:100)
    at com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionImp.rollback(UserTransactionImp.java:140)
    at com.vs.framework.service.BlfServiceAtomIkosBean.executeService(BlfServiceAtomIkosBean.java:80)
    at com.dbhl.app.presentation.action.CreateUnitTypeAction.execute(CreateUnitTypeAction.java:128)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.servlet.ExecuteAction.execute(ExecuteAction.java:58)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.AbstractExecuteAction.execute(AbstractExecuteAction.java:67)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.ActionCommandBase.execute(ActionCommandBase.java:51)
    at org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:190)
    at org.apache.commons.chain.generic.LookupCommand.execute(LookupCommand.java:304)
    at org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:190)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.ComposableRequestProcessor.process(ComposableRequestProcessor.java:283)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:462)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler.invoke(JkCoyoteHandler.java:190)
    at org.apache.jk.common.HandlerRequest.invoke(HandlerRequest.java:291)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.invoke(ChannelSocket.java:769)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.processConnection(ChannelSocket.java:698)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket$SocketConnection.runIt(ChannelSocket.java:891)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:690)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Log already in use?
    at com.atomikos.icatch.standalone.UserTransactionServiceImp.createDefault(UserTransactionServiceImp.java:205)
    at com.atomikos.icatch.standalone.UserTransactionServiceImp.init(UserTransactionServiceImp.java:265)
    ... 31 more
Nested exception is:
```

while i googling common solution from [here](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/CARBON-10378)

```
Are these instances running in a single machine? .. like, are those running in an app server, where it is pointed to a single CARBON_HOME? .. if so, the "transaction.properties" file have to be removed from /repository/lib and should be put into each WARs classpath location. And each "transaction.properties" file has to be edited to change the log file location. This error comes when more that one instance is trying to access the same transaction log file of Atomikos, or there's also a chance that the earlier JVM shutdown was not done properly and the lock file wasn't released. In that case, you simply have to remove the log file at /repository/data/tmlog.lck file and restart the server.
```

i follow this advise .
remove property file from tomcat/common/lib to my war's classpath .
changed directory accordingly above mentioned.
i also check for tmlog file but it does not exist on the server.

but nothing works . still the error occurs.

if you see at atomikos page [here](http://www.atomikos.com/Documentation/KnownProblems#Log_Already_In_Use)

```
The lock file in question is created to protect the transaction logs against accidental duplicate startups. Otherwise, the logs could get corrupted when two instances of the same transaction manager are recovering on the same data. Normally, it suffices to follow the hints and then delete the lock file manually if needed.
```

it just states follow the hints , **but where is the hint ??**

please help me to re solve it.

atomikos is the open source,

i checked the source code and found the below lines which is throwing exception

```
if ( enableRecovery ) {
             //ISSUE 10077: don't complain about lock file if no logging
            try {
                lockfilestream_ = new FileOutputStream ( lockfile_ );
                lock_ = lockfilestream_.getChannel().tryLock();
                lockfile_.deleteOnExit();
            } catch ( OverlappingFileLockException failedToGetLock ) {
                //happens on windows
                lock_ = null;
            } catch ( IOException failedToGetLock ) {
                //happens on windows
                lock_ = null;
            }
            if ( lock_ == null ) {
                 System.err.println ( "ERROR: the specified log seems to be "
                        + "in use already. Make sure that no other instance is "
                        + "running, or kill any pending process if needed." );
                throw new RuntimeException ( "Log already in use?" );
            }
        }
```

**i have already set debugging to false in jta.properties
com.atomikos.icatch.enable_logging=false
and restart my server but still the same error.**

### Update after Guy Padron Answer

> @Guy Pardon thanks for this answer.i know you are the owner of the
>   AtomIkos , i am often get mail from you. the problem is that for your
>   free open source version you hard coded default properties in the code
>   , so if any user ties to set it from the property file it is not
>   overriding. in my case what was the problem , the log file is created
>   in the current directory by atomikos by its default properties and
>   hence no problem on the local environment but whenever it is uploaded
>   to shared hosting where creating is file or directory inside server's
>   bin folder is not permitted and hence the above error, so i debug the
>   code , modify it according to my need and got success in Aug,2012.
>   when i inspect your code i found that your code is throwing wrong
>   exception in my described situation as well and there are so many
>   points the code can be improved.

Thank You
Mihir Parekh

Answer (score 7):

When you have more than one project (that uses Atomikos) deployed, this problem occurs due to concurrency on writing atomikos' log files (*Error message: 'Log already in use'*).

To solve this problem *you must customize the log file name*, *setting the property* **'com.atomikos.icatch.log_base_name'** *in atomikos configuration* as exemplified below:

```
<bean id="atomikosUserTransactionService" class="com.atomikos.icatch.config.UserTransactionServiceImp"
      init-method="init" destroy-method="shutdownForce">
    <constructor-arg>
        <props>
            <prop key="com.atomikos.icatch.service">com.atomikos.icatch.standalone.UserTransactionServiceFactory</prop>
            <prop key="com.atomikos.icatch.log_base_name">your_project_name_log</prop>
            <prop key="com.atomikos.icatch.output_dir">../standalone/log/</prop>
            <prop key="com.atomikos.icatch.log_base_dir">../standalone/log/</prop>
        </props>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

P.S.: Note that I've changed the properties '**com.atomikos.icatch.output_dir**' and '**com.atomikos.icatch.log_base_dir**' just to keep the things organized, creating atomikos' log files in the same directory of JBoss log files.

Answer (score 4):

there is a lock file that must be removed in order to startup your container again. Its name is tmlog.lck. At Apache 7 it is located at APACHE_HOME/bin/

Good luck.

Comment: thanks for your answer. actually i solved it by my own and the solution is different then specified when i have some time i will write here with complete description.

Answer (score 1):

This is a permission issue. I added this two line in my `jta.properties`.(confirm the dir is exist).

```
com.atomikos.icatch.output_dir = /data/logs/XXX/
com.atomikos.icatch.log_base_dir = /data/logs/XXX/
```

Answer (score 1):

In our case the reason was completely different:

We configured our tomcat8 instance to contain all needed Atomikos .jars.
That was mainly as described here:
[Atomikos Tomcat 7 Configuration](https://www.atomikos.com/Documentation/Tomcat7Integration35)

In our Spring application configuration we needed to define the J2eeTransactionManager (due to the "transaction suspension not available" problem already described [here](https://blog.codecentric.de/2012/03/integration-eines-transaktionsmanagers-in-tomcat-zur-nutzung-in-spring-und-openjpa/)):

```
@Bean
public TransactionManager atomikosTransactionManager() {
    return new J2eeTransactionManager();
}

@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager txManager() throws Throwable {
    JtaTransactionManager jtaTransactionManager = new JtaTransactionManager();
    jtaTransactionManager.setAllowCustomIsolationLevels(true);
    jtaTransactionManager.setTransactionManager(atomikosTransactionManager());
    UserTransaction ut = userTransaction();
    jtaTransactionManager.setUserTransaction(ut);
    return  jtaTransactionManager;
}
```

So you need a reference to the pom.xml in your application, but this reference has to have the "provided" scope:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.atomikos</groupId>
        <artifactId>transactions-jta</artifactId>
        <version>3.9.3</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

In our case, we omitted the scope and therefore tomcat and our application created it's own instance of the transaction manager and that resulted to the "log already in use" error message.

So deleting the .lock-file helped here, too. After deleting the lock-file the application specific transaction manager could obtain the lock and was running fine; but after a tomcat restart, you would get the same error message again.

Since I found this cause nowhere else, maybe this is helpful to others...

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure there isn't any other JVM running on your production server that could lock the atomikos transaction log ?

Comment: i have this plan http://www.dailyrazor.com/java-jsp-hosting/private-tomcat-hosting and i have razor expedition . it is multi instance so i think there should be more than one JVM. so what should i do in this situation ??

Comment: I just got reply from support Dear Customer,Your private Tomcat is a single instance. so what should i do now ?

Answer (score 0):

A little late maybe, but this typically happens if you have multiple transaction manager instances (JVMs) using the same logs. Just try not to do that :-)

HTH

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same error, but the scenario was different.
Atomikos creates a different java process, and in my case that java process was running in infinite loop in unix box, although I stopped the tomcat container.

So I found out that java process using below command.

```
ps -ef | grep java | grep -v grep
```

And killed using this command

```
kill -9 pid
```

Started the tomcat again, and it worked fine.

Comment: Not sure what you mean - but Atomikos does not create a separate Java  process. It runs embedded in the application's JVM.

Answer (score 0):

```
<bean id="atomikosUserTransactionService" class="com.atomikos.icatch.config.UserTransactionServiceImp"
  init-method="init" destroy-method="shutdownForce">
<constructor-arg>
    <props>
        <prop key="com.atomikos.icatch.service">com.atomikos.icatch.standalone.UserTransactionServiceFactory</prop>
        <prop key="com.atomikos.icatch.log_base_name">your_project_name_log</prop>
        <prop key="com.atomikos.icatch.output_dir">../standalone/log/</prop>
        <prop key="com.atomikos.icatch.log_base_dir">../standalone/log/</prop>
    </props>
</constructor-arg>
```

This works for me but I don't understand the role of your_project_name_log in this code.