# com.atomikos.icatch.SysException: Error in init: Log already in use? tmlog in ./

Tags: java, spring, atomikos

I have a very big problem with my atomikos. I cant create bean because of below error:

*org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'authenticatingSignInAdapter': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userRepoAutowired': Error creating bean with name 'userRepo': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.atomikos.icatch.SysException: Error in init: Log already in use? tmlog in ./; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepo': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.atomikos.icatch.SysException: Error in init: Log already in use? tmlog in ./*

I read a link: [solve error : log already in use with atomikos with multiple instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12305700/solve-error-log-already-in-use-with-atomikos-with-multiple-instances). but nothing helped me. Do you know what can be a problem? It is only one bean that cant be created.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are starting multiple instances on the same log folder / log file.